# If $x^2<a-a^2-2ax$ and $x^2<b-b^2-2bx$ then $x^2 < ab$?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a,b,x$ be positive reals such that $a+b+x\le 1$. Moreover, we know that

(i) $x^2 < a-a^2-2ax$

(ii) $x^2< b-b^2-2bx$

Is it true that 
$$
x^2 < ab\,\,?
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Choose $a=b$ sufficiently small and $x=a+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$.